# How make descendant width not depending on it's parent width

Tags: css

I have vertical drop down menu, and I want that the sub menu will be vertical too. 
Seemingly, if you set `float:left` for the sub menu `li` it should be fine, but the problem is, that the sub menu `ul` which is nested in `li` has a width that depends on it's parent (`li`) width and don't expands enough, so that the lines (`li`) of sub menu are presented vertically.
You can see an example: http://jsfiddle.net/r6qNJ/

I thought about two solutions:

**Solution 1:**
Expanding a width of a nested `ul` to a very big one

```
 ul.sub{width:999px;}
```

**The problem is**, that by this way I have to dissable a background and border of a sub menu `ul`, as it has a non nature width.
An example: http://jsfiddle.net/r6qNJ/1/

**Solution 2**
Using `display:flex` property, so that the width of a child element will not depend on it's parent width.
An example: http://jsfiddle.net/r6qNJ/2/
**The problem is**, that it's not supported in old browsers.

So, what is more elegant and efficient CSS solution you can offer?
(I am looking for a pure CSS solution, without changing HTML, since I am talking about changing in wordpress theme and prefer to make changes only in css files)

Comment: You could use `position: absolute`. If your parent `li` doesn't have `position: relative` then it's width would inherit from whatever the parent `li`'s parent's width is.

Comment: Yes. The only problem is, that if I remove `left:0`  and I have padding in parent `li` elements, the sub menu will be places not in the right place. But it can be fixed with negative `margin-left`. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have this option with `white-space`:

```
ul.sub{  
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:100%;
  padding:0;
  display:inline-block;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
ul.sub li{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:-4px;
  width:80px;
  float:none;
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/r6qNJ/23/**

Comment: oh wow! didn't know about that for regular elements. Very helpful!